# LDAP-Server using ldapjs on TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, ldapjs

I want to host an LDAP Server using [ldapjs](http://ldapjs.org/index.html). Sadly there is no documentation for TypeScript yet. So I found the typings in `@types/nodejs` but there are no server methods present:

```
import ldap = require('ldapjs')
let server = ldap.createServer()
```

This gives me an error in VS Code that no method called `createServer` is present. Only `createClient` is showing. Also the `index.d.ts` from the Typings package contains only a `Client` interface:

`export interface Client extends EventEmitter { // ...`

How can I get the correct Typings for server usage?

Answer (score 0):

ldapjs server is currently not properly typed.

The fast solution is to type ldapjs as `any`. This will remove type errors from your code.

```
const ldap: any = require('ldapjs')
```

The longer solution would be to contribute to the ldapjs typing with a pull request to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/ldapjs